# Pass Data from Activity to Fragment in Viewpager Tablayout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I used below code to passing data from Activity to Fragment.

**Fragment Code**

```
public class StoryDetailFragmentInfo extends Fragment {
View view;
TextView txtDescrible;

final static String getData = "abc";

public static StoryDetailFragmentInfo newInstance(String paramater){
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(getData,"Message");
    StoryDetailFragmentInfo fragmentInfo = new StoryDetailFragmentInfo();
    fragmentInfo.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragmentInfo;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(getArguments()!=null){
        String test = getArguments().getString(getData);
    }



}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.story_detail_fragment_info_layout, container, false);

     txtDescrible = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_describleDetail);

    return view;
}
```

}

**MainActivity Code**

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.story_detail_layout);
    addControls();
    loadData();
    intentData();
    fillDataToView();
}

private void intentData() {
    StoryDetailFragmentInfo.newInstance("Hello babe");

}
```

Problem is `getArgument()` in my fragment is `null` and i can't get data What should i do?
Can you help me explain it? Thanks for reading.

Comment: Did you attached the `Fragment` to this `Activity` ? Are you commiting a transiction anywhere else in the code that you're omitting ?

Comment: Ye.I have attached and This communication is unique

Comment: Show me the code where you are making the transaction between the activity and the fragment

Comment: i don't make with transaction. Because i used tablayout and i think it don't have container layout

Comment: You're not making much sense. Put both `xml's` from MainActivity and StoryDetailFragmentInfo

Comment: Let's me see............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you want to pass data from activity to fragment as initial data, you can send data from activity to ViewPagerAdapter, then pass data from ViewPagerAdapter to fragment in getItem() function.
   In Activity:

   adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this,false));
   adapter.setData(data);

In ViewPagerAdapter:

```
    @Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
            fragment.setData(data);
            return fragment
    }
}
```

2. If you want to pass data from activity to fragment in real time (like updating data), I recommend to use EventBus. It is a modern and convenient tool to communicate between activity and fragment. Check it at https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, in the method `newInstance` of class `StoryDetailFragmentInfo`, you write these:
`bundle.putString(getData,"Message");` while leave `paramater` alone. So you need change

```
 bundle.putString(getData,"Message");
```

to

```
 bundle.putString(getData,paramater);
```

Secondly, you try to get values from arguments from fragment by the key 'AdapterStoryDetailViewPager.idData', but this key is different from the key which you used to save value. So you need to change

```
String test = getArguments().getString(AdapterStoryDetailViewPager.idData);
```

to

```
String test = getArguments().getString(getData);
```

After these two steps, you would get the right value.

Comment: I understand what you say but this problem is getArguments() is null

Comment: @NguyễnViệtĐức There is one thing you must be careful. You need call `setArgument` before you add or show fragment(before start `beginTransaction`).